# Memory leak on unawaited tasks which throw exception?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, clr

Below is a simple console app code, which repeatedly fires an async call but doesn't await. The called function throws an exception.
Running this console app produces following results:

- In VS under debugger - the memory usage is flat. No leaks.
- Run the exe directly (outside of vs and not under debugger) - the memory keeps growing to gbs and eventually OOMs at around ~4gb.

I am not sure how to explain these results. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Task.Run(() => RunMain());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static Exception ex = new Exception();
    private static void RunMain()
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

edit: 
I am primarily interested in why the memory leaks when unobserved exceptions are thrown continuously.

Comment: Curious. I can't test this right now by myself, but is it a requirement for the observed behavior that the same and only Exception object instance is being thrown by several concurrent threads? Or would the same curious behavior also occur when each task creates its own Exception instance?

Comment: I think its leaking on both Debug and Release mode, even if you catch exceptions. With **debugger attached** however, your code runs much slower so it may seem flat but its not. if you zoom in to process memory from diagnostics tool. Its strange. if you collect generation 0 it does not leak. GC is not working somehow.

Comment: @elgonzo - No. It is not a requirement. But I did this just to eliminate the possibility of creation of new Exception objects too many times.
The same behavior is observed when each task is creating its own exception.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - You are right that it is leaking on both debug and release mode. About debugger slowing down the leaks - that is possible. 
Ofcourse my primary interest is in figuring why the leak, than why it is so slow when under debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you constantly create new tasks with that Task.Run(), you’re creating new objects that are taking up more memory. I believe what you’re overlooking is the fact that the Task itself is an object.

When you call Task.Run(), you add a Task to the queue of the Threadpool. I would bet that the memory leak is from new tasks continually being added to the Threadpool’s queue and the threadpool not being able to keep up with it.

Comment: I think the main question is. Why is the GC not able to collect all those tasks?

Comment: I’m not in a position to test right now, but I would guess that it’s not that the GC isn’t collecting the tasks and that the Threadpool just isn’t able to keep up with that much concurrency. The Threadpool will only start adding new available tasks after it has had stuff in the queue for a period of time, and then it only adds 1 Task at a time

Comment: with `GC.Collect(0)` this program has no leaks. so i think its the GC that is not figuring out when to collect. (it can collect if you call it manually)

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more. I believe @TimRobinson is on point. The tasks are created very fast so they haven't been run yet (just enqueued). They aren't being GCed because those tasks are still live.

Comment: Thanks @TimRobinson. That seems to be the case. 
I replaced throw in RunMain with a sleep(10) and got similar results with memory growth. I am not sure if there is a way to limit the thread queue size.

Another interesting thing I noticed was, if the GC doesnt kick in for sometime, then we also start accumulating the UnobservedExceptions which are fired all at once when GC collection kicks in. This also seems to add to the Memory pressure, but I am not sure.